JACK audio: swap/remap channels
I have a M-Audio fasttrack USB interface that has a mic input and an instrument input. Mic is channel 1 and instrument is channel 2, which is the opposite of most other interfaces that have this layout, including my Line 6 pod X3. So, to load my presets/patches in, let's say, carla, for the time being i have to either (1) manually connect the right JACK inputs to each carla instance when i'm using the interface that doesn't match, or (2) have several copies of each patch file, one for each interface. This is kind of annoying because i need to use one of multiple interfaces depending what i'm doing (recording, jamming with friends, etc)
Is there a way to swap or remap the channels directly from JACK, like for example some undocumented commandline/config option - or through a proxy client that would then be used as input for carla/renoise/etc?
